# Extract date from string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, string, substring

I have columns of string data formatted like this:

```
Katy Perry Tickets - Staples Center. 09/19/2014 7:30 PM. 209 11

Atlanta Braves Tickets vs Miami Marlins Tickets - Turner Field. 08/31/2014 5:10 PM. 411L 2
```

I need to extract the date value from each field, and the common format is looking at the first full stop from the right until the next full stop. The date is always between those two.

A full stop occassionally occurs in the text to the left of the date so we can't trust that.

How can I get that particular substring? SQL gurus, your advice needed...

Thanks.

Comment: don't do it in mysql. mysql regexs can do matching only. they can't do capturing. You're stuck with basic string manipulations, and even those can be highly painful in sql. use a regex to pull out only records that have what looks to be dates in them, then use client-side code to do the actual extraction.

Comment: Have you tried the SUBSTR (read SUBSTRING) function? What have you tried?

Comment: Cheruvian below has got the perfect solution using Substring_Index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `Substring_Index`

```
Select  Substring_Index(Substring_Index( txt, ".",  -2), ".", 1)
From    Tablename
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [PREG functions for mysql](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg) , I have installed the UDF functions and I get this:

1- Creating and inserting sample data:

```
create table your_table (
    txt_col text
);

insert into your_table values  
('Katy Perry Tickets - Staples Center. 09/19/2014 7:30 PM. 209 11'),
('Atlanta Braves Tickets vs Miami Marlins Tickets - Turner Field. 08/31/2014 5:10 PM. 411L 2');
```

2- Testing the `PREG_CAPTURE` function using a pattern for dates:

```
mysql> SELECT PREG_CAPTURE(
           '/([0-9]+\\/[0-9]+\\/[0-9]+)\\s[0-9]+:[0-9]+\\s[a-z]+/i' , 
           txt_col, 0  ) as date_captured, 
    txt_col from your_table;
+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| date_captured      | txt_col                                                                                    |
+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 09/19/2014 7:30 PM | Katy Perry Tickets - Staples Center. 09/19/2014 7:30 PM. 209 11                            |
| 08/31/2014 5:10 PM | Atlanta Braves Tickets vs Miami Marlins Tickets - Turner Field. 08/31/2014 5:10 PM. 411L 2 |
+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

`date_captured` column is the extracted text.